# add index and change int data type to bigint the fastest way

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, mysql-5.7

How do I do this without downtime, or at least minimal downtime (less than 3 hours)?

[image: Here are my.cnf config]

Is there any way to tweak `my.cnf` to at least make this process of indexing and change data type faster?

Below is the table structure that I would like to update.

```
CREATE TABLE user_rew (  u_reward_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                         promo_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,    
                         user_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,  
                         msisdn varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,  
                         reward_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,  
                         serial_no varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
                         pv_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
                         is_gw tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  
                         is_claimed tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,  
                         created_at datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
                         updated_at datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
                         PRIMARY KEY (u_reward_id),  
                         KEY promo_id (promo_id),  
                         KEY reward_id (reward_id),  
                         KEY is_claimed (is_claimed),  
                         KEY is_gw (is_gw),  
                         KEY serial_no (serial_no),  
                         KEY pv_id (pv_id ),  
                         KEY user_id (user_id,msisdn) ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: 1) What field must be converted to BIGINT? 2) What index must be created? 3) Do you REALLY need in this huge pack of single-field indices? 4) How much memory is installed on your server?

Comment: Hi Akina!
1. u_reward_id, right now the max value present in the table is 1327159947 it is nearing the max value of int(11)
2. the updated_at field
3. Yes
4. 256 GB

This is just a test instance, if in case we would be upgrading our production environment, we need to do a simulation as to how long will the indexing and change data type take place.

Comment: 1) Put this info into question text. 2) In any case you cannot use INPLACE, only ALGORYTHM=Copy is available. 3) Add `innodb_sort_buffer_size` info.

Comment: In any case study [Online DDL Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html) - to decrease the estimated time you need to build operations chain which is fully INPLACE. It can be (add new column) - (copy data from u_reward_id) - (drop PK and add new) - (drop column) - (add secondary index).

Comment: Is there a column or combination of columns that is unique?  I am fishing for whether you can get rid if `u_reward_id` instead.

Comment: While you are fixing the PK, get rid of the indexes on flags; they are probably useless.  OTOH, the _may_ be useful as the first column in a composite key.  Note:  The fewer indexes you have, the faster the PK-fix will finish.